# How to bring a menu to front of a navigation frame in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, navigation, canvas, frame, z-index

I Have a Silverlight page with a header menu, a navigation frame, and a footer. In my header menu I want to put a drop down menu, but when I open the menu, it goes behind the frame.

Is there a way to put it forward? `Canvas.ZIndex` makes no difference at all.

Answer (score 1):

For me to get this to work, the navigation frame had to be in a grid that was a child of the grid my menu was in.

Like so:

> Grid "FullPageGrid"
>      Grid
>         Menu Stuff
>         Grid
>            Navigation Frame

Not sure why that works, but it does.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this free opensource menu for this purpose:

[www.sl4popupmenu.codeplex.com](http://www.sl4popupmenu.codeplex.com)

It brings the content on top by placing in a Popup control.

Answer (score -1):

If you can place the drop down menu later in the XAML, it will appear above.

So you want to have this hierarchy:

```
Grid
    Grid
       Your navigation frame
    Grid
       The menu
```

Comment: How its possible navigation is in upper and menu selection is in down like task bar?